# How to Import Web Generated Content Into a Java Application?

Tags: java, html, hibernate, function, web

I'm looking to use an online name/description generator to generate a data set for a hibernate database using a website's free generators (http://fantasynamegenerators.com/ancient-greek-names.php#.VRzNuuFSKu8), but I can't figure out how to call the name generation functions that are defined in the source on the page. How should I go about doing this from a Java application? Can you provide an example?

Comment: If you examine carefully the source of the html, you will find that the names are generated by calling `nameGen()` which is inside a `.js` file of the site, e.g. `ancient-greek names` has it in `scripts/ancientGreekNames.js`. In this `.js` file, there declared arrays that house all the possible names from which the html just randomly pick 10 for display each time you click the `Get male names` button. Simply gather these `.js` files and you will have all the names.

Comment: Other type of `.js` files generate names by randomly combine pre-defined words, e.g. `bandit name` using `scripts/thiefNames.js`. You can copy the javascript from it and go through all the combinations to save them into DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option to try is to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html and obtain the source of the page. Then you can fetch or process the content by observing java script functions. Or also you may decide to use inbuilt [Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) for running java script functions.